# IntelliJ IDEA is too slow during run or debug

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I optimize the `vmoptions` and delete all of the breakpoints of `IntelliJ IDEA`, but it is still too slow during run or debugging. I also turned off my Antivirus app (KIS) and tried many suggestion on some issues on Stackoverflow, but does not fix the problem. So, is there any proper way to fix this?

Note: I use version **2021.1.3**

Comment: What is the last thing the terminal outputs before it starts taking a long time?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html

Comment: Please contact JetBrains support team at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new , and provide additional information as per https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241235-Reporting-performance-problems .

Comment: Also, try using the 2021.2 build version from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download and temporarily disable all third-party plugins. (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html)

Comment: @UrDistraction It is always slow from the beginning to build.

Comment: @EgorKlepikov Thanks a lot, I know that option but from I have seen JetBrains support forums, it seems that there will be nothing except from useless  time spending with "try this". So, I have nothing special and I also tried by turning off antivirus app. So, this problem must have been encountered by someone else before. On the other hand, I also disabled lots of the plugins, but these plugins are already used before and there was no slowness problem. I mean, there is nothing changed related to them.